# Cannot read propery of .includes undefined - react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to map this array but the it keeps saying `.includes is undefined`. I assume maybe its because I've mapped is wrong? I'm not sure but I will list everything I have.

Here is what my api data looks like when I `console.log(this.props.tournaments` it from from my redux store:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjghN.png)

You see the `undefined` in the first index of the array, I've used an `Object.keys(tournaments).map(key => tournaments[key])` and `.map` (which you can see in the component snippet below) twice which when I console.log I get the correct results but I still get an error when its passes through the `.filter` function.

Here is what it looks like after I've formatted the array:
[console.log after formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh8yT.png)

but I'm still getting an error...

This the error I'm getting:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5swG.png)

**Here is the component in question:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTournaments } from '../actions/tournaments';

class Search extends React.PureComponent {
  // State only needs to hold the current filter text value:

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTournaments();
  }

  state = {
    filterText: ''
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ filterText: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {

    let tourns = this.props.tournaments.map(tore =>
      tore.map(room => room.name)
    );

    console.log(tourns, 'here');
    const filteredList = tourns.filter(item =>
      item.name.includes(this.state.filterText)
    );

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.filterText} />
         <ul>{filteredList.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}</ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ tournaments }) {
  return {
    tournaments: Object.keys(tournaments).map(key => tournaments[key])
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchTournaments
})(Search);
```

My data is coming from redux like so:
Reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENT,
 from '../actions/types';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TOURNAMENT:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action:

```
import {
  FETCH_TOURNAMENT,
} from './types';

import { API_TOURNAMENTS_URL } from '../constants/api';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchTournament = id => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/tournaments/${id}`);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOURNAMENT, payload: response.data });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could treat you response.data before setting to state to reflect more how you will be handling your application. I would imagine that you would rather have an array of objects.

you could try passing to payload `Object.values(response.data).flat()` instead which would give you an array of of objects based on your response.

#### Edit

below is without implementing `Object.values(response.data).flat()`. if you follow the suggestion you shouldnt need to treat

about the issue at filter, `item` is an array containing name value at index 0. this is why you get undefined. this happens because of `tore.map(room => room.name)` returns an array.

if you change as below you may get your array of tourns:

```
let tourns = this.props.tournaments.flat();
```

but I would consider to treat your response which would avoid all these changes on component level. pick one which suits you better.

Comment: I've added the `Object.values(response.data).flat()` to the actions and added `let tourns = this.props.tournaments.map(tore => ({ name: tore[0].name }));` but the only problem is that it only retreives the first name and I want it to retrieve a name based on the search criteria

Comment: I see, I edited my answer. I think you should pick one approach. Or you treat your response right away (which I believe it makes more sense), or do these manipulations at component. if you call flat at your arrays of arrays then you you will get an array of tournaments.

Comment: if it still fails then let me know